# Ionic add new page and add that page to Side Menu not working

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm working on ionic based app. That has few pre-built things.

I wanted to add about page into the app. I've used "ionic g page about" and created the page.

However, after this step, I'm struggling to add this to the side menu. Side menu already have login / register / cart pages.

I've copied login (side menu) codes and managed to change it to About. However, I'm can not navigate to about page when I click About link from side menu.

(Definitely I'm doing something wrong and I tried with several youtube videos. But still, I didn't get a solution).

If anybody can please help me.

Comment: can you show some code

Comment: @SappyGoofy - I'm not sure which code I should give you. Sorry I'm very new to ionic as well as android app development.

Do you need the code I used under app.html ?

Just to let you know after I created the page, then I use import code in the app.mudule.ts and then came to app.html and used the code as I explained above.

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: <ion-item tappable full menuClose (click)="AboutPage()")>
<ion-icon item-left name=md-home">
</ion-icon> {{"About" | translate}}
</on-item>

Comment: No. It's passing through and push the app to the phone and I can run and test it. Only thing is "About" link on side menu is not working.

Comment: what is inside AboutPage() function

Comment: BTW when use ionic serve and test, it shows AboutPage is not defined error on the top.

Comment: Nothing in the AboutPage() function

Comment: can u try this - https://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-adding-pages-and-navigation/

Comment: @SappyGoofy - Thanks. That's the one I followed the first place. Let me try again. Not sure if I missed something there. I will try again and let yuo know.

Comment: This didn't work. 

Do you know can I add external link to side menu ? (I meant if I have about page in my website, can I link that... www.example.com/about something like this ?